# Console Errors during XPM load

Tags: 2013-sp1, experience-manager

When I load XPM for a given page I see the following errors

**Firefox 47**
[image]

**Chrome - 50**
[image]

In Firefox, XPM largely functions correctly (albeit slowly). In Chrome I occasionally experience the "Finish Editing" button not responding to clicks or a never ending "committing all changes" message.

Comment: I've seen similar behaviour when the staging site was trying to load JS from a domain other than it's own when in XPM mode but the errors more more clear.